# Find/filter includes array by ids vue js

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

Hello guys i've tried to filter like this
for result like this using filter and includes.. but not work, any solution using includes or something?

```
companies ids
[1,2,3]
user companies ids
[1,2]
filtered result
[1,2]
```

i've tried like these

```
this.company.filter(company => company.id.includes(this.reviewerData.company_ids))
```

but output justlike []

thanks guys

Comment: includes function can't accept a array as parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let companiesids = [1,2,3];
let userids =  [1,2];

let results = companiesids.filter(f => userids.indexOf(f) > -1);
console.log(results);
```

**UPDATED:**

```js
let companiesids = [{id: 1, name: 'a'},{id: 2, name: 'b'},{id: 3, name: 'c'}];
let userids =  [1,2];

let results = companiesids.filter(f => userids.indexOf(f.id) > -1);
console.clear();
console.log(results);
```

Comment: ithink thats work, but i have company like this

`company{id:1, name:"balala"}` `usercompanyids: [1,2]`

Comment: Do a map for company first, and then do filter. company.map(m => m.id)

Comment: if i mapping.. how can i display name?